# Printing variable value

Tags: tcl

I have written the following code to create a variable with suffix

```
set a 1
set x$a 20
```

But I'm not able to print the value stored in the second variable.

What command helps me to print the value of `x1` (`x$a`) variable ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it would be more useful for you to use arrays:

```
set a 1
set x($a) 20
puts $x($a)
# 20
```

But if you cannot use that, then you could use this way:

```
set a 1
set x$a 20
puts [set x$a]
# 20
```

Comment: Another option is to alias the variable: `upvar 0 x$a theAlias; set theAlias 20; puts $theAlias`